# How to automate to check when a code signing certificate expired

Tags: certificate, code-signing-certificate

I have a desktop application created with signed binaries and a code signing certificate that expires in a year, just as a reminder I want to keep checking when the certificate expires. Is there a way I can automate this?

Comment: can you access this certificate from another application to check it's expiration time? what is the platform?

Comment: I believe we cannot use a third party application, It is Windows Platform. Maybe some script that we can run to identify the expiration date? @oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run openssl command line utility to print the expiration time of the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in <your certificate file>
```

The output is something line this:

```
notAfter=Feb 10 12:05:45 2023 GMT
```

Then you can create a script that will run periodically and will check this value